Can I trigger PagerDuty Incident with SNS only?

I'm trying to get paged in pagerduty when a new object is created in my S3 bucket with prefix 'invalid-files/'. I've created a NotificationConfiguration for S3 that publish to my SNS topic. I also have a cloudwatch integration and I tried to use that URL to subscribe to my topic but it didn't work. It seems the event has to maintain a schema otherwise PD won't trigger any incident.
Few alternative I found but I'm looking for something better. 

Custom Event Transformer do the job but we are using PagerDuty terraform provider to maintain  PD. And seems like Custom Event Transformer is not available in terraform provider.
I can use SQS instead of SNS for the S3 NotificationConfiguration and then consume the message from a lambda and do something about it. but it feels like a overkill for getting a notification for object creation.
I can set alarm on the SQS without the lambda, but then I have to purge the queue everytime I get an alarm.

Is there a simple idea that I can use to trigger PD incident for S3 object creation?

Another option could be an App Event Transformer -- you won't be able to terraform the App metadata, but once you have the app ID (still called a vendor_id in the service/integration endpoints), you should be able to terraform your services with that, and avoid duplicating the custom event transform across multiple services.
